# DeclarationError: Identifier already declared. Two imports import the same ERC721 contract

Tags: error, openzeppelin, import, erc-721

Im building a contract that uses two contracts that both use the ERC721 zeppelin contract, when I import the two as such:

```
import nonFungableWidthAddedFunctionality1.sol;
import nonFungableWidthAddedFunctionality2.sol;
```

I get the following error:

```
$PATH DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
import "./../nonFungableWidthAddedFunctionality2.sol";
^--------------------------^
$PATH The previous declaration is here:
contract ERC721 {
^
```

Both of these contracts need the ERC721 implementation since they are also used separately.

Comment: If you just need to call the ERC721 functions from your third contract, you can just import the ERC721 definition, instead of the individual token contracts.

Comment: But both the tokens have different implementations and augmentations of the standard ERC721 protocol.

Comment: Your solution did work after looking through the ERC721 interface a bit more careful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring contract ERC721 more than once, thus the error.

Essentially, you're doing this:

```
contract Contract1 {
}

contract Contract1 {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by collisions between IERC20.sol from an openzeppelin module and my own IERC20.sol file that I had in my interfaces folder. For my own smart contracts I was using my own IERC20.sol, while some of my imported contracts were using the IERC20.sol file found in the openzeppelin module.

As a simple solution I removed my personal IERC20.sol file and instead only used the IERC20.sol interface provided by the openzeppelin module.